# Android, loading picture closes application

Tags: android, image

My app loads init values from the database in the onCreate method of the main activity.
Debugging, I've noticed that when I press the button to load an image starting a new activity, the debugger shuts down and, in fact, when I return to the app, the onStart method is re-executed.

I call this to start the activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

I'm testing on a smartphone that has 256Mb of ram, could this be the problem ?
I mean, there's not enough ram so the app gets closed and then reopened when the load image activity finishes.
Which would be the best way to avoid a reload of the init values ?

Comment: Have you tried in on the emulator? and given it more ram? Also post a logCat.

Comment: @SeahawksRdaBest: I tried in an emulator but it didn't find any picture. This should not matter I guess... anyway, the app was not shut down. Or maybe it matters as in the smartphone it loads many pictures to show the thumbnails. I'll post a log later, thanks.

Comment: the logCat https://www.dropbox.com/s/kmxegvdzeo8dzia/logCat.log?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's definitely the lack of RAM, I'm testing now on a phone with 1GB and it doesn't happen.
But a phone with low RAM is a really good test system especially for testing the save/restore instance.
It's all broken but still running so I will not throw it away.